# Non-Integral Pointer Type

Tags: llvm

Изучаю LLVM IR. Читаю из [**LLVM Language Reference Manual**](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constants). Никак не могу понять "смысл" этой строкуи

> Non-integral pointer types represent pointers that have an unspecified bitwise representation; that is, the integral representation may be target dependent or unstable (not backed by a fixed integer).

Объясните что за ***non-integral pointers***?

> P.S. вопрос не связан с переводом :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю, что это тип указателя с ограниченным числом операций. В отличие от обычного указателя, где допустимы сложения, вычитания и может быть даже битовые операции, равно как и хранение в регистрах разного рода, этот тип явно запрещает любые манипуляции и преобразования из/к численному виду.

На данный момент, это экспериментальная фича.

> non-integral pointer types are a work in progress, and they should be considered experimental at this time.